# Assembly not found error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using WebcamControl;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace SMS
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for camphoto.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class camphoto : Window
    {
        public camphoto()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            Binding bndg_1 = new Binding("SelectedValue");
            bndg_1.Source = comboBox1;
            webcam1.SetBinding(WebcamControl.Webcam.VideoDeviceProperty, bndg_1);

            //set properties
            webcam1.PictureFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg;

            webcam1.FrameRate = 30;
            webcam1.FrameSize = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 240);

            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            string str = Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDeviceType.Video.ToString();

                FindDevice();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        private void FindDevice()
        {
            var vidDevice = Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDevices.FindDevices(Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices.EncoderDeviceType.Video);
            foreach (var data in vidDevice)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(data.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi Friends, This is my code what it is preview to webcam. But one error is coming when I'm debugging this.

> "File Not found Exception was cought : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified."

I'm already added `Microsoft.Expression.Encoder` reference to project references. But I don't understand why it is coming. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Project Properties** -> **Build** section and change **Platform target** to **x86**

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your project profile is NOT `".Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile"`. If so please change to `".Net Framework 4.0"`.

Also ensure that the references section has the dll reference. Try to clean the solution and then rebuild and also cross verify the dll in the `bin` directory once.

Comment: Yes! it is already select as .net framework 4.0 in project application properties. No effect is appear.

Comment: check in the references section whether you have a different version other than `4.0`.

Comment: Also try to empty the Temporary ASP.Net files folder and then check it once

Comment: so many times i did check, but i didn't understd why it is comming? and i'm using this in wpf